# Hierarchical dynamic tree

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to create a dynamical hierarchical tree in ADF. My requirement is that there are no control in the number of nodes or branches.

Is this possible in ADF or do we have to do this in the code?

Say

```
Profession -
         IT - 
             Appication Developer
             Web Developer
             Mobile Developere here
```

This would be a sample of the tree but the point is the nodes can also have nodes under it.

How do I do this in ADF?

Answer (score 1):

When you drag and drop from data controls, select `Hierarchy Viewer`.

For an example, please look into [Hierarchy Viewer example](http://www.gabrielsideras.com/2010/10/17/the-hierarchy-viewer-component/)

Comment: @zDroid are you able to move forward?